# Check validation has run and failed with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, validation, codeigniter

How can I check that form validation has run and failed? Using:

```
$this->form_validation->run() == FALSE
```

Will run even if the validation hasn't run, ie: when the form is first loaded (blank state). I am using forma validation to show individual errors. However I have quite a long form and I'd like to also show a message at the top of the form, saying something like:

```
There were errors submitting the form, please check the individual errors below
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do:

```
if (validation_errors()) echo 'There have been errors...';
```